# Moqui Framework - Error: no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, moqui

I'm encountering an issue while working with a Java Content Repository (JCR) using **Apache Jackrabbit with moqui**. When attempting to access or manipulate a property named "data," I receive the following error message: **no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data**

I'm unsure why this error is occurring and how to resolve it. Here's some additional information about my setup:

```
I'm using Apache Jackrabbit version jackrabbit-standalone-2.11.3.jar
I'm using Moqui Framework version 3.0
```

i'm trying to add a new Wiki Space under Marble ERP > Wiki Space to a JCR repository and selecting content://main/WikiSpace as the Root Page Directory
and getting the  error no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data

Error running groovy script (javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data):

despite these efforts, the error message "no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data" still persists. I expected that by addressing the potential configuration or code issues, I would be able to access the "data" property without encountering this error.

Can someone with experience in Moqui or JCR integrations please help me understand why I'm encountering this error within the Moqui framework and how to resolve it? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)